# Gentoo wifi setup issue: wpa_supplicant works but wpa_cli doesn't

Tags: linux, gentoo, wpa-supplicant, ifconfig, wpa2

I am trying to setup Gentoo on my laptop and am having trouble connecting to wifi. I've never done this before, so I might be making a simple mistake.

I've been following [these instructions](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Networking/Wireless). My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file is:

```
# not sure if all of the next 4 lines are necessary
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
ctrl_intrface_group=0
ap_scan=1

network={
    ssid="<SSID>"
    #psk="<password>
    psk=<password as numbers>
}
```

When I run wpa_supplicant, I see:

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp4s0 -c /etc/wpa_suplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.10
...
Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (nil) - re-trying

^C

# iw wlp4s0 link
Not connected.
```

Things I've checked:

1. SSID and password are correct
2. Network interface is up:

```
# ifconfig
wlp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>...
```

The wifi network uses WPA, not WPA2/3, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you try `wpa_cli -s/var/run/wpa_supplicant` as root?